# Removing a key-value pair from HashMap is giving an error during for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, nullpointerexception, hashmap

I have a set of data stored in a HashMap. The elements in the data are compared and if the condition is satisfied, they are removed from the elements. However, I am using a for loop to iterate the elements and it is giving me a Java Null Pointer error.

```
Example of comparisons:

Item: 0-1
Item: 0-2
Item: 0-3
Item: 0-4
Item: 1-2
Item: 1-3
Item: 1-4
Item: 2-3
Item: 2-4
Item: 3-4

Condition: IF Item 0-1 > (1-2, 1-3 and 1-4): store value 0-1 in another array 
           then remove Item 0-1, 1-2, 1-3 and 1-4 from HahsMap list. ELSE continue to next set
Condition: IF Item 0-2 > (2-3 and 2-4): store value 0-2 in another array 
           then removed Item 0-2, 2-3 and 2-4 from HahsMap list. ELSE continue to next set.

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class TestHashMapLoop {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        myMap.put("0-1", 33);
        myMap.put("0-2", 29);
        myMap.put("0-3", 14);
        myMap.put("0-4", 8);
        myMap.put("0-5", 18);
        myMap.put("1-2", 41);
        myMap.put("1-3", 15);
        myMap.put("1-4", 17);
        myMap.put("1-5", 28);
        myMap.put("2-3", 1);
        myMap.put("2-4", 16);
        myMap.put("2-5", 81);
        myMap.put("3-4", 12);
        myMap.put("3-5", 11);
        myMap.put("4-5", 21);

        int myMapCount = 6;

        for(int i = 0; i < myMapCount; i++)
        {
            for(int j = i+1; j < myMapCount; j++)
            {
                String indexKey = i+"-"+j;

                for(int k = 0; k < myMapCount; k++)
                {
                    String compareKey = j+"-"+k;                        
                    System.out.println("Index " + indexKey + " : " + compareKey);

                    if((myMap.get(indexKey)) > (myMap.get(compareKey)))
                    {
                        //Store value indexKey in another array (not shown here)
                        System.out.println("Index" + myMap.get(compareKey) + " is removed..");
                        myMap.remove(compareKey);
                    }
                    System.out.println("Index " + myMap.get(indexKey) + " is removed..");
                    myMap.remove(indexKey);
                }
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

Can anyone advise on how to get the loop going even though the elements are removed or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What should the end result look like? Why are you doing this? Are you trying to do a weighted search a of a map?

Comment: It's part of an algorithm that I am trying to get it working. I stored the values in a HashMap because I need a way to iterate the list in a certain way. Is this a dumb way of doing it?

Comment: How did you decide that your `myMapCount` would be 6??

Comment: @Cryssie Ok, What are you trying to achieve? What should the end result look like? Are you trying to do a weighted search a of a map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first iteration

```
indexKey = 0-1;
   compareKey=1-0;

if((myMap.get(indexKey)) > (myMap.get(compareKey)))
```

your mymap.get("1-0") would return **null**

**EDIT:**

As **Fildor** said in the comments:

```
check if myMap.get(indexKey) and myMap.get(compareKey) are NUll  
IF Null
Continue your innermost loop
else continue what ever you were doing .
```

Comment: ... and to keep the thing going, check get(indexKey) and get(compareKey) for null and continue if they are.

Comment: @Fildor i am not sure what the OP want to acheive. i was only pointing out that myMap.get(compareKey) would return null. thus incomplete answer :)

Comment: Well he asked "Can anyone advise on how to get the loop going even though the elements are removed" ... so, your answer + my comment = solution :)

Comment: Just to clarify..I'm a 'she' and Fildor that's a good idea. Just to make sure I understand your answer..I can still remove the elements from HashMap but I need add one check condition for null values to keep the loop going?

Comment: @Cryssie yepp, you have to check for nulls while iterating.

Answer (score 0):

Removing all the `keys` whose `value` is `less` than a particular `key-value` pair will be a trivial task.

Because you have to compare "0-1" with all those elements starting with "1-", and if you find that all the elements are less than "0-1", then only you will remove them.. So, you will have to iterate over your map, to remove them..

A better way would be to create another `map`, where you can put the element "0-1" after you find that it is greater..

I would rather use enhanced-for loop..

```
public class TestHashMapLoop {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        Map<String, Integer> newMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        /** Initialize Map **/

        boolean flag = true;
        Set<String> keySet = myMap.keySet();

        for (String key: keySet) {
            flag = true;
            for (String innerKey: keySet) {

                if (innerKey.startsWith(String.valueOf(key.charAt(2)))) {

                    if (myMap.get(key) > myMap.get(innerKey)) {
                        continue;

                    } else {
                        flag = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
            if (flag) {
                newMap.put(key, myMap.get(key));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(newMap);
    }
}
```

But, this is also not a very good way. Notice that this way you are iterating over a `map with n keys :- n * n times`

You would rather want to find a better way than using a `HashMap` for what you want to do..